# issue when i try to display a background image using Canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

I'm trying to display a background image using `g.drawImage` within `Canvas Jframe` but i have nothing displayed and the screen still white , and when i try to fill the screen with any color it works using `g.fillRect`

here is the Main class :

```
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.PolygonShape;
import org.jbox2d.common.Vec2;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyDef;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.FixtureDef;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.World;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 600, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

    // rate to convert meters to pixels in the physics engine
    public static final float RATE = 30;

    // counts how many loops are made in the main thread
    private int counter = 49;

    // image and graphics used for double buffering
    private ImageIcon bgImage = new ImageIcon("res/bgImage.png");
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;

    /* boolean to define when the game will be started and stopped */

    private boolean running = false;


    // variables for the Box2D world
    Vec2 gravity = new Vec2(0.0f, 10.0f);
    boolean doSleep = true;
    World world = new World(gravity, doSleep);

    // new array list to hold Ball references
    ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    // create a new player
    Player character = new Player(world);



    public Main() {

        addKeyListener(this);

        // add a ground floor to our Box2D world
        BodyDef groundBodyDef = new BodyDef();
        groundBodyDef.position.set(300.0f / RATE, 400.0f / RATE);
        Body groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);
        PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();
        groundBox.setAsBox(300.0f / RATE, 0);
        groundBody.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f);

        // wall fixture
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = groundBox;
        fixtureDef.density = 2.0f;
        fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = -1;

        // left wall
        groundBodyDef.position.set(0.0f / RATE, 350.0f / RATE);
        groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);
        groundBox.setAsBox(0, 50.0f / RATE);
        groundBody.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        // right wall
        groundBodyDef.position.set(600.0f / RATE, 350.0f / RATE);
        groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);
        groundBox.setAsBox(0, 50.0f / RATE);
        groundBody.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        /**
         * @WIDHT : width of jpanel screen
         * @HEIGHT : height of the jpanel screen
         * @param : title of jpanel screen
         * @this : refered to our main game instance 
         */

        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Apocalypse 2D v0.0", this);


    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() { // Width of the CustomPanel
        return WIDTH;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() { // Height of the CustomPanel
        return HEIGHT;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() { // Dimension of the CustomPanel
        return new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }



    public void start() {
        // starts a new thread
        running = true;
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void destroy() {

    }


    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

        while (running) {
            counter++;

            // Simulate the world
            float timeStep = 1.0f / 60.0f;
            int velocityIterations = 6;
            int positionIterations = 2;
            world.step(timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);


            // add new balls to the world every 50th loop
            if (counter % 80 == 0)
                balls.add(new Ball(world));

            repaint();

            // pause for 10 milliseconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // do nothing
            }

            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        /*g.setColor(Color.black);*/
        /*g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());*/
        g.drawImage(bgImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

        // loop through each ball and call it's draw method
        Iterator<Ball> itr = balls.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Ball b = itr.next();
            b.DrawBall(g);

            // if the ball should be removed then remove it
            if (b.shouldDelete())
                itr.remove();
        }

        // draw the main character.
        character.draw(g);



    }

    // sets up double buffering for graphics
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        if (dbImage == null) {
            dbImage = createImage(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        }

        dbg.setColor(getBackground());
        dbg.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

        dbg.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(dbg);

        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);

        character.animplayer();

        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            ball.animBalls();
        }

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        character.keyPress(key);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
        character.keyRelease(key);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

and this is the paint method where i'm trying to fill the image to the screen :

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

        /*g.setColor(Color.black);*/
        /*g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());*/
        g.drawImage(bgImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

        // loop through each ball and call it's draw method
        Iterator<Ball> itr = balls.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Ball b = itr.next();
            b.DrawBall(g);

            // if the ball should be removed then remove it
            if (b.shouldDelete())
                itr.remove();
        }

        // draw the main character.
        character.draw(g);



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drawImage()` method has several overloads, the one you are using is `drawImage(BufferedImage img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)`, `x` and `y` being the top left coordinates on the canvas. Right now those are the width and the heigh of the canvas, so the image is being drawn outside of the panel. Try calling `g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null)`.

### edit:

Asuming your image is not the same size as your canvas, use `g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null)` to fill the canvas with your image.

Comment: i still get a syntax error i'm using an imageIcon and the type of drawImage first parameter must be Image , and when i change it i get another syntax error with this : private Image bgImage = new Image("res/bgImage.png");

Comment: Try using a `BufferedImage` instead. To create a new `BufferdImage` from a `File`, use `BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/file"))`.